# How to parse each column in a CSV file using C

Tags: c, parsing

I'm trying to use C to read a CSV file, iterate line by line (until EOF), and delimit/split each line by the comma. Then I wish to separate each column into "bins" and put add them to a struct (which isn't shown here; I defined it in a helper file) based on type.

For example, if I have `1,Bob`, I'd like to split `1` and `Bob` into two variables. Here's what I've written so far.

```
void readFile(char file[25]) {
    FILE *fp;
    char line[1000];

    fp = fopen(file, "r"))

    while(fgets(line, 1000, fp)) {
        char* tmp = strdup(line);
        char* token;

        while((token = strsep(&tmp, ","))) {
            printf("%s\n", token);  // I want to split token[0] and token[1]
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

T he above code does compile and run. I just don't know how to access each split of the `token`, like `token[0]` or `token[1]`. In python, this would be simple enough. I could just access `1` using `token[0]` and `Bob` using `token[1]` for each `line`. But here in C, I can't do that.

For testing purposes, all I'm doing right now is printing each line (in the second `while` loop), just to see how each split looks. I haven't implemented the code where I put each split line into its respective struct member.

I've searched Stack Overflow and found a multitude of threads on this topic. None of them seemed to help me except for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39364170/parsing-csv-file-by-splitting-with-strsep), which I have drawn from. But I wasn't able to get the storing of split columns working.

Comment: If nothing else, you have a memory leak in your code. Don't forget that `strdup` allocates memory which you need to `free`.

Comment: I would look into `strtok`. It's how I did it before.

Comment: Also note that [`strsep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html) is not a standard C function. And that you probably need to read its documentation a little closer (if you still want to use it instead of the standard C [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function).

Comment: What would I change in my code to get it to work with `strtok`? From reading some documentation, it looks like it has largely the same format as `strsep`. Can I also get the second chunk of text, or does it only give one chunk of text (or token) at a time?

Comment: Additionally there is no law or decree that says a CSV row must be less than 1000 characters long... If you're on POSIX consider using `getline` instead! And you probably *don't need* to `strdup` the line either if you duplicate each of the fields or parse them in place there...

Answer (score 1):

> In python, this would be simple enough. I could just access `1` using `token[0]` and `Bob` using `token[1]` for each `line`. But here in C, I can't do that.

Yes, you can, if only you define the array.

```
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
    {
        char *tmp = strchr(line, '\n');
        if (tmp) *tmp = '\0';   // remove the '\n'
        tmp = strdup(line);
        #define MAXCOLUMNS  2
        char *token[MAXCOLUMNS];
        int c = 0;
        while (tmp)
        {
            if (c == MAXCOLUMNS) puts("too many columns"), exit(1);
            token[c++] = strsep(&tmp, ",");
        }
        if (1 <= c) printf("column 1: %s\n", token[0]);
        if (2 <= c) printf("column 2: %s\n", token[1]);
        // ONLY if the line's tokens are no longer needed:
        free(*token);
    }
```

Comment: This is useful to know, thanks. But I don't know what `char *token[MAXCOLUMNS]` does. It looks like you're defining a new character array, `token`, that's of length MAXCOLUMNS. But why do you use a `*`? Wouldn't just `char token[MAXCOLUMNS]` do the same thing?

Comment: @WaterGuy - `char *token[MAXCOLUMNS]` (with MAXCOLUMNS 2) declares an array of 2 pointers to `char`, i. e. a pointer array, not a character array. The first of those pointers, `token[0]`, is later set to the beginning of the (`strdup`-licated) line and the first column, and the second of those pointers, `token[1]`, is set to the second column.